# Form validation and email sending: Is it better to have one php script or two separate?

Tags: php, forms, email, validation

I have a form which should have some required fields. If some fields are missing the already filled out fields should not be lost. Therefore the values are set again. How should the processing look like?

I can use only one php script (form action = `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`), which does everything including sending a mail when finished.

Or should I use an form.php for the form and an form_do.php for the processing? How can I hand over the POST values from form_do.php to form.php?

Which of these possibilities is the better one?

Edit:

I tried to set the POST values with this code

```
$referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

header('POST ' . $referer . ' HTTP/1.1');
header('Host: '. $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
header(implode(',',$_POST));
```

but it doesn't open in the browser. Instead it tries it to open with Notepad ... What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: neither is better. they are both fine and widely used.

Comment: How can I hand over the POST values from form_do.php to form.php?

Comment: how about in the POST header.

Comment: views and business logic should be in separate files. for easy maintainability

Comment: @Dagon: Can you post a link or an example how I can set values in the POST header? form.php makes this through `<form action="" method="post" ...`. But how can I make this manually?

Comment: curl() is the easy way, or you could shove the post array in to a session and just header redirect to the form page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `<form action="form_do.php" method="post"` to send h

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this would work. In my `form_do.php` I only should have the validation and e-mail sending. You say that I should use HTML within that. How do I get the array `$_POST` in the form?

Comment: It looks like my original comment got truncated somehow—sorry for that. You would use HTML in `form.php`, but `form_do.php` wouldn't need any HTML; it could use PHP only and retrieve the post data from the `$_POST` array.